# Error while using Double.parseDouble to an Object that has been caste as String

Tags: java

I'm writing an infix evaluator program and I'm having trouble with this statement:

```
c = Double.parseDouble((String) operands.pop());
```

"operands" is a stack which stores the operands. The .pop() method returns an object of type T (Since the stack is an ArrayList of type T). Since Double.parseDouble requires a string as parameter, I have caste it to a string.

However, I am receiving this error:
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.String

What mistake have I made?

Comment: maybe you can share the full code so we can see how operands is initialized.

Comment: It cannot cast `Double` to `String`, which means that `pop()` is returning a `Double` object. Which part of the error message confused you about that? Just do `c = (Double) operands.pop();`

Comment: parseDouble has also some overloads so not only string is possible, why would You be doing parseDouble on an object that already is double? For any other object that someghow resolves as a string that resembles a number its safer to use .toString()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception is actually happening on the expression

```java
(String) operands.pop()
```

You can't cast a double to a string using `(String)` because it is not a safe cast.

The compiler is telling you that the value given by `operands.pop()` is already a double!

If you want to do the cast, you will need to use the `toString()` method on it first.

Answer (score 0):

Exception is indicating that pop method is returning object of java.lang.Double() so no need to cast and parse it. Even if you want to cast and parse because of some reason then use String.valueOf(operands.pop()).